# Update if the register exists otherwise insert. MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Let's suppose I have the following table in a MySQL DB

Table: Debt

```
ID | Customer | Amount
---------------------
1  | Peter    | $ 80
2  | John     | $120
```

What I want to do is sum a new amount of money to the already pending one for a given customer. What I've been doing so far is a `SELECT` to check if the customer exist in the table. If it does then I `UPDATE` the register with the sum of the previous value plus the new one. If the register doesn't exist the I proceed to `INSERT`.

As you can see I'm using two operations, a `SELECT` and an `UPDATE`, or a `SELECT` and and `INSERT`.

My question is if there is a way to do this with only one single operation

Comment: Please show a more robust example of data, what the table looks like before your intended query runs, and what it looks like afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Set amount = amount + ?? in the on duplicate update clause.

Answer (score 0):

MySql does allow to update an existing record or insert one, use `INSERT INTO table (id, name, amount) VALUES (1, 'Peter', 80) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE;`

I don't know though if you could use the existing value to do a sum with the new and insert the result.

Probably you'd need triggers for that...